# Task Manager only showing 3 GB memory used from 8GB

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have 8GB Ram installed but in Task Manager it is showing that I am using 93% of my memory, even though I am using no more than 3.5GB.

Where is the rest?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Services, graphics

Comment: Virtual machine software, such as would be used in the device emulator, may not show properly or under the same program. If you are emulating a mobile phone with 4GB of RAM then that would explain where the rest of your memory went.

Comment: @Mokubai hi mokubai. i added more images. please check :)

Comment: So you close Android Studio and everything goes back down? Sounds normal. Just because the top 5 **named** processes are using only 2.5 GB doesn't mean your system isn't using it for other processes and services. Without any programs running Windows will use 2-3GB just to do it's work, running Android Studio and qemu (Android Emulator) will use more on top of that. You need to look at the *entire* list in task manager, not just 3-5 of your favourite items.

Comment: that list is descending if there are process that consuming more memory, it will appear on top. thats last image i already close emulator and android. i am honestly asking whats the point i hide any other app that consumer a lot of memory.so there is no point i only show u my favourite app